# how to get multiple dropdown list value in jQuery when i clone multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click button clone is worked but it is showing value only one dropdown list
i want to get value clone multiple dropdown list and  show the alertbox
there is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnid').click(function() {

    $('#idcuntry').clone().attr('id', 'id_' + $(this).index()).insertAfter('#idcuntry');
    var a = $('#idcuntry').val();
    alert(a);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="idcuntry">
  <option value="10">Selection </option>
  <option value="20">Pa </option>
  <option value="30">India </option>
</select><br/>
<input type="button" value="clone" id="btnid">
```

Comment: You only have ONE idcuntry so you will only ever clone that

Comment: ...and, in any cases, IDs must be unique... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are getting the value of `#idcuntry`, and there's only one with this ID (which is good, IDs should be unique, so you made the right choice of changing the ID of your clones).

To target multiple elements, you can add a class to them, for example `class="countryselect"`.

Then, `.val()` will only return the value of the first element. But you can use `.map()` to get them all in an Array:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnid').click(function() {
      $('#idcuntry').clone().attr('id', 'id_' + $(this).index()).insertAfter('#idcuntry');
      var a = $('.countryselect').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).get();
      alert(a);
    });
  });
</script>
<select id="idcuntry" class="countryselect">
  <option value="10">Selection </option>
  <option value="20">Pa </option>
  <option value="30">India </option>
</select><br/>
<input type="button" value="clone" id="btnid">
```